# Excel Replace Using Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to Replace a Cell with other Cell Text, the think is i need to removed some text from an Image URLs using Excel Formula.

**Image URL** : domain.com/images/products/63/63/19787/2/279/image-name.jpg

Text that i needed to be removed is **279/**. But i need it to be removed at the exact place like **domain.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/x/279/image-name.jpg** between URL and Image name.

I've tried to split it first with this Formula

```
=MID(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),LEN(A1))
```

Result after i used the Formula

> /279/image-name.jpg

and i tried using Replace Formula to replace text from other cell text. Before that i removed the /279 from the result so its only /image-name.jpg now.

```
=REPLACE(A1, FIND(B1,A1), 4, C1)
```

But its keep giving me double result in the end of the text like this

[image]

> domain.com/images/products/63/63/19787/2/image-name.jpg/image-name.jpg

result should be

> domain.com/images/products/63/63/19787/2/image-name.jpg - without 279/

is there any problem with the Replace Formula ? or is there any other simpler Formula to make it work ?

Comment: is it always 279?

Comment: Change last parameter in `=REPLACE(A1, FIND(B1,A1), 4, C1)` to `""`. Because you want to replace the found text with an empty string.

Comment: Yes its always 279 in exact position before image-name.jpg, but there are sometimes more 279 in different position, if i used Replace all instead it will delete the other 279 on the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the location of the next to last slash:

```
=FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1))
```

If the contents of that node will always be three characters, you can use replace:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),"")
```

If the contents of that node will be a variable number of characters, then we first return the part up to that node, and concatenate with the last node:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1),99))) &
TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

**EDIT** *Logic added to ensure that the next to last node is equal to `279`*

If you need to confirm that the next to last node contains `279`, you can check it with:

```
=ISNUMBER(N(FIND("/279/",MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),99))=1))
```

Using that as part of an `IF` will return the original string if `279` is not the contents of that node, and replace it only if it is:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(N(FIND("/279/",MID(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),99))=1)),
LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",CHAR(1),LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1),99))) &
TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",REPT(" ",99)),99)),A1)
```

Comment: Why use any of these if the `279` is a constant? It seems like there are a lot more formulas being used than what is necessary.

Comment: I used the third formula and it works completely without replace text.

Comment: the thing is to removed the 279 text before the image-name.jpg without using Replace and avoid deleting other 279 in the same URLs.

Comment: @rullymnh I just read your note now that `279` is a constant.  Do you need to confirm that there is, indeed, a `279` in the next to last node before removing it?  If so, the formulas will need additional logic.

Comment: There are some URLs with more then one 279 like domain.com/images/products/63/279/19787/2/279/image-name.jpg, it just need to remove the 279 that next to image-name.jpg

Comment: @rullymnh ok. Any of the formulas should work then.

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to have access to `TEXTJOIN` then use:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(position() = last()-1)]"))
```

And if you need to check if it's equal to '279' before removal:

```
=TEXTJOIN("/",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[not(position() = last()-1 and .='279')]"))
```

If you don't have access to `TEXTJOIN` then you have a fine alternative by @RonRosenfeld.

Another option would be to use `REPLACE()`:

```
=REPLACE(A1,FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))))-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/","|",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/",""))-1)),"")
```

Comment: This is also working effective just like @RonResenfeld Formula without me trying to separate text to other cells. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the `SUBSTITUTE()` function.

The below finds "/279/image-name.jpg" and replaces it with "/image-name.jpg". The added `/image-name.jpg` will ensure other instances of `/279` will remain unaltered.

`A1 value = "domain.com/images/products/63/63/19787/2/279/image-name.jpg"`

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"/279/image-name.jpg","/image-name.jpg")
```

output:

```
domain.com/images/products/63/63/19787/2/image-name.jpg
```